# Display a range of dates based on current date, in Python

Tags: python, date, datetime, time, strftime

```
import datetime

print datetime.datetime.now().strftime("Week of %m/%d") 
    #returns "Week of 04/18"
```

I want it to print "Week of 4/11 to 4/18" (with 4/13 being exactly one week beforehand) 
and it would need to account for if the week ended on 4/3, then it would be "Week of 3/27 to 4/3"

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: What programming language are you using? Add a tag, and perhaps mention in title.

Comment: @BasilBourque Thanks, edited post to show language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`dateutil.relativedelta`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-ba5ffd4df8111d1b83fc194b97ebecf837add454) will do what you want:

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import *

march27 = datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 27)
print (march27 + relativedelta(weeks=+1)).strftime("Week of %m/%d")
#prints "Week of 04/03"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using only stdlib `datetime` module:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

now = date(2014, 4, 18)
print now.strftime('Week of %m/%d')
# -> Week of 04/18
weekbefore = now - timedelta(days=7)
print "Week of {weekbefore:%m/%d} to {now:%m/%d}".format(**vars())
# -> Week of 04/11 to 04/18
```

It works the same if `now = date(2014, 4, 3)`. It prints `Week of 03/27 to 04/03` in this case.